# QML ComboBox crashes on embedded System

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols, eglfs

I added a ComoboBox in my program to my qml. 
This runs fine on desktop (both Ubuntu and Win7). As soon as I deploy my program on my embedded linux machine (sabrelight with yocto) it crashes as soon as I try to open the list of items from the ComboBox.

Anyone encountered a similar behaviour? Any idea why that happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens because ComboBox from Qt Quick Controls 1 creates a top-level window for the popup. Creating multiple top-level windows is not supported on EGLFS on Embedded Linux.

You may want to give it a try with [Qt Quick Controls 2](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-index.html) introduced in Qt 5.7. It is embedded and mobile friendly by providing item-based popups and an order of magnitude better performance.

You can read more about the history [here](http://blog.qt.io/blog/category/qt-quick-controls/). In particular, [this post](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2015/03/31/qt-quick-controls-for-embedded/) highlights the fundamental structural changes in Qt Quick Controls 2.